# paypal sandbox empty after login

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

The `Paypal sandbox system` is completely out of order. After dealing with many different issues (such as login cookies issue), now a new issue has come and I cant find a way to solve it.

Using `express checkout`, after reaching paypal sandbox page it will show cart preview on the left, and on the right it will show login section. Then when I login with sandbox buyers id, the right section just goes blank... nothing... no redirect, no pay button, no nothing.

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: What browser are you using? Can you provide steps to reproduce the problem? I just tested with my own Buyer / Seller account and I didn't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue after deleting test accounts from developer.paypal.com and creating new test accounts....

It must have been some internal issue in BugPal (I mean PayPal)....